# T-SQL string manipulation, replacement, comparing, pattern matching, regular expressions

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-server-2005

I have a short string of alphanumeric characters A-Z and 0-9

Both Characters AND Numbers are included in the string.

I want to strip spaces, and compare each string against a 'pattern' of which it will match only one. The Patterns use A to denote any character A-Z and 9 for any 0-9.

The 6 patterns are:

```
A99AA
A999AA
A9A9AA
AA99AA
AA999AA
AA9A9AA
```

I have these in a table with another column, with the correct space in place :-

```
pattern PatternTrimmed
A9 9AA  A99AA
A99 9AA A999AA
A9A 9AA A9A9AA
AA9 9AA AA99AA
AA99 9AA    AA999AA
AA9A 9AA    AA9A9AA
```

I am using SQL Server 2005, and I don't want to have 34 replace statements changing each of the characters and numbers to A's and 9's.

Suggestions on how I can achieve this in a short succinct way, please.

Here's what I want to avoid :-

```
update postcodes set Pattern = replace (Pattern, 'B', 'A') 
update postcodes set Pattern = replace (Pattern, 'C', 'A') 
update postcodes set Pattern = replace (Pattern, 'D', 'A') 
update postcodes set Pattern = replace (Pattern, 'E', 'A')
```

etc.

and

```
update postcodes set Pattern = replace (Pattern, '0', '9') 
update postcodes set Pattern = replace (Pattern, '1', '9')
update postcodes set Pattern = replace (Pattern, '2', '9')
```

etc

Basically, I am trying to take a UK postcode typed in at a call centre by an imbecile, and pattern match the entered postcode against one of the 6 above patterns, and work out where to insert the space.

Comment: update postcodes set Pattern = replace (Pattern, 'B', 'A')
update postcodes set Pattern = replace (Pattern, 'C', 'A')
update postcodes set Pattern = replace (Pattern, 'D', 'A')
update postcodes set Pattern = replace (Pattern, 'E', 'A')
etc.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
 Declare @table table
(
ColumnToCompare varchar(20),
AmendedValue varchar(20)
)

Declare @patterns table
(
Pattern varchar(20),
TrimmedPattern varchar(20)
)

Insert Into @table (ColumnToCompare)
Select 'BBB87 BBB'
Union all
Select 'J97B B'
union all
select '282 8289'
union all
select 'UW83 7YY'
union all
select 'UW83 7Y0'

Insert Into @patterns
Select 'A9 9AA', 'A99AA'
union all
Select 'A99 9AA', 'A999AA'
union all
Select 'A9A 9AA', 'A9A9AA'
union all
Select 'AA9 9AA', 'AA99AA'
union all
Select 'AA99 9AA', 'AA999AA'
union all
Select 'AA9A 9AA', 'AA9A9AA'


Update @table
Set AmendedValue =  Left(Replace(ColumnToCompare, ' ',''), (CharIndex(' ', Pattern)-1)) + space(1) + 
                    SubString(Replace(ColumnToCompare, ' ',''), (CharIndex(' ', Pattern)), (Len(ColumnToCompare) - (CharIndex(' ', Pattern)-1)))
From @table
Cross Join @Patterns
Where PatIndex(Replace((Replace(TrimmedPattern, 'A','[A-Z]')), '9','[0-9]'), Replace(ColumnToCompare, ' ' ,'')) > 0

select * From @table
```

This part

`Left(Replace(ColumnToCompare, ' ',''), (CharIndex(' ', Pattern)-1))`

finds the space in the pattern that has been matched and takes the left hand portion of the string being compared.

it then adds a space

`+ space(1) +`

then this part

`SubString(Replace(ColumnToCompare, ' ',''), (CharIndex(' ', Pattern)), (Len(ColumnToCompare) - (CharIndex(' ', Pattern)-1)))`

appends the remainder of the string to the new value.